# Parsing XML in R data stored in attributes with blanks

Tags: xml, r, api

I am trying to parse the data contained in an XML file using R. I would like the data to be read into a dataframe. The data is located at the following URL:

http://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde/report_format/latest-July-2015-New-Format.xml

I have reviewed some similar posts on stackoverflow such as [How to convert xml data to data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821284/how-to-convert-xml-data-to-data-frame-in-r) but I still cannot seem to get them to work. One issue I ran into is that some of the values are empty and then appear like this:

```
<Cell Textbox73="filler" />
```

The general key value pair is structured as follows:

```
<m1_attribute_group>
   <s3 attribute1="Trade 2/">
       <s4>
           <Cell cell_value1="372.02"/>
       </s4>
   </s3>
</m1_attribute_group>
```

Is there any way to parse this file quickly with xmlToDataFrame() or xmlAttrsToDataFrame() or do I have to build custom functions to apply over the list of nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to know exactly what you want extracted. So, dissection is required. This USDA XML output is quite involved across commodities, year/months, and regions with changing nodes for attributes and text/cell values.

Consider an XSLT transformation. As information, [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) is a special-purpose declarative language that transforms XML files into any nuances for diverse purposes. While other programming languages like R can parse various elements, values, and attributes from XML files, XSLT is specially designed to re-format whole documents to specific needs. Often considered, the *forgotten language* in the web data age, it can be very useful to transform complex xml data.

For your purposes here is a simple XSL stylesheet to extract Output, Total Supply, Trade, Total Use, and Ending Stocks from various commodities (two `value-of` declarations are made due to the changing xpaths of the USDA data):

**XSLT STYLESHEET**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="data">
     <xsl:for-each select="//m1_commodity_group/m1_year_group_Collection/m1_year_group
                            /m1_month_group_Collection/m1_month_group/m1_attribute_group_Collection">
      <xsl:element name="m1_attribute_group">

      <xsl:element name="Output">          
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group/s3[@attribute1='Output']/s4/Cell/@cell_value1"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group_Collection/m1_attribute_group[@attribute1='Output']/Textbox12/Cell/@cell_value1"/>  
      </xsl:element>      

      <xsl:element name="TotalSupply">          
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group/s3[@attribute1='Total Supply']/s4/Cell/@cell_value1"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group[@attribute1='Total&#13;&#10;Supply']/Textbox12/Cell/@cell_value1"/>
      </xsl:element>      

      <xsl:element name="Trade2">          
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group/s3[@attribute1='Trade 2/']/s4/Cell/@cell_value1"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group[@attribute1='Trade 2/']/Textbox12/Cell/@cell_value1"/>      
      </xsl:element>      

      <xsl:element name="TotalUse3">          
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group/s3[@attribute1='Total&#13;&#10;Use 3/']/s4/Cell/@cell_value1"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group[@attribute1='Total&#13;&#10;Use 3/']/Textbox12/Cell/@cell_value1"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="EndingStocks">          
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group/s3[@attribute1='Ending&#13;&#10;Stocks']/s4/Cell/@cell_value1"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="m1_attribute_group[@attribute1='Ending&#13;&#10;Stocks']/Textbox12/Cell/@cell_value1"/> 
      </xsl:element>

      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<data>
  <m1_attribute_group>
    <Commodity>Total Grains 4/</Commodity>
    <MarketYear>2013/14</MarketYear>
    <Output>2474.27</Output>
    <TotalSupply>2930.14</TotalSupply>
    <Trade2>372.02</Trade2>
    <TotalUse3>2417.87</TotalUse3>
    <EndingStocks>512.27</EndingStocks>
  </m1_attribute_group>
  ...
</data>
```

Nearly all programming languages (i.e., Java, C#, Python, PHP) have XSLT transformation libraries, including R with the [Sxlst package](http://www.omegahat.org/Sxslt/). However, below is an R script interfacing with VBA calling the Windows [MSXML COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763701%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object. It requires the [RDCOMClient](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/) library, an easy installation with RStudio. This is only a Windows PC solution.

**R SCRIPT**

```
library(XML)
library(RDCOMClient)

# CREATE INSTANCES OF MICROSOFT XML OBJECTS 
xmlfile = COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xslfile = COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
newxmlfile = COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

xmlstr = "http://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde/report_format/latest-July-2015-New-Format.xml"
xslstr = "C:/Path/To/XSLFile.xsl"
newxmlstr = "C:/Path/To/TransformedXMLFile.xsl"

# LOAD XML & XSLT FILES
xmlfile.async = FALSE
xmlfile$Load(xmlstr)

xslfile.async = FALSE
xslfile$Load(xslstr)

# TRANSFORM XML FILE USING XLST INTO NEW FILE
xmlfile$transformNodeToObject(xslfile, newxmlfile)
newxmlfile$Save(newxmlstr)

# CONVERT TRANSFORMED XML INTO R DATA FRAME
doc<-xmlParse("C:/Path/To/TransformedXMLFile.xml")
xmldf <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//m1_attribute_group"))

# UNINITIALIZE MSXML OBJECTS 
xmlfile <- NULL 
xslfile <- NULL
newxmlfile <- NULL
```

Above stylesheet renders the following data frame:

**DATA FRAME**

```
    Commodity   MarketYear  Output  TotalSupply Trade2  TotalUse3   EndingStocks
1   Total Grains 4/ 2013/14 2474.27 2930.14 372.02  2417.87 512.27
2   Total Grains 4/ 2014/15 (Est.)  2492.63 3004.90 375.54  2464.63 540.27
3   Total Grains 4/ 2015/16 (Proj.)     2479.30 3010.96 360.65  2489.78 521.18
4   Total Grains 4/ 2015/16 (Proj.)     2477.26 3017.53 362.61  2485.14 532.39
5   Wheat   2013/14 715.11  892.24  165.92  698.72  193.52
6   Wheat   2014/15 (Est.)  725.92  919.44  163.94  707.38  212.06
7   Wheat   2015/16 (Proj.)     721.55  921.96  158.41  719.56  202.40
8   Wheat   2015/16 (Proj.)     721.96  934.01  158.07  714.20  219.81
9   Coarse Grains 5/    2013/14 1280.98 1449.07 164.39  1237.67 211.40
10  Coarse Grains 5/    2014/15 (Est.)  1290.43 1501.83 168.58  1272.56 229.27
11  Coarse Grains 5/    2015/16 (Proj.)     1276.00 1508.58 159.74  1281.23 227.35
12  Coarse Grains 5/    2015/16 (Proj.)     1274.97 1504.24 162.30  1282.17 222.07
13  Rice, milled    2013/14 478.18  588.83  41.72   481.48  107.36
14  Rice, milled    2014/15 (Est.)  476.28  583.64  43.02   484.69  98.95
15  Rice, milled    2015/16 (Proj.)     481.74  580.43  42.51   488.99  91.44
16  Rice, milled    2015/16 (Proj.)     480.34  579.28  42.24   488.78  90.51
```

Comment: Wow I haven't heard of it but i'll give it a shot, thanks

Comment: unfortunately, I have to do this in windows and no one seems to have figured out how to install the Sxlst package in windows...back to the drawing board

Comment: Do you have MS Excel or MS Access installed? VBA can transform XML with [MSXML object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763701(v=vs.85).aspx)? Alternatively, open-source [PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742972/transform-xml-with-xslt-in-php) and [Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698935/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-using-xslt-in-python) can run xslt files. For above, I used Python.

Comment: See my edits above. I now include a pure R script that calls the MSXML object using the RDCOMClient library. This should allow you to transform XML files with XSLT stylesheets.